# Clebsch–Gordan(CG) coefficients for SO(N) and Sp(N) group

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I know how to calculate the CG coefficients for $SU(N)$, but there are other simple Lie group like $SO(N)$ and $Sp(N)$. But up to now I can't find any textbook tells me how to calculate these and I also can't find tables for these. So where I can find tables of CG coefficients for $SO(N)$ and $Sp(N)$. Really thanks.